# Plotting both x and y messes up y values in graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Plotting with just the y plots a graph exactly as intended but I want to use another column from the same dataframe for the x-axis. Doing so messes up my y plots though. I can't figure out why.

Here's the section of the code in question:

```
temps = df['temps']       # floats
hours = df['timestamps']  # ints

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(hours, temps)
```

[image]

If I leave out `hours` and just do `ax.plot(temps)`, it looks right.

[image]

Both `hours` and `temps` are the same length. How do I get the `hours` as the x-axis values without ruining my y-plot?

Comment: Well, your hours are rounded hours, so they are plotted on rounded (integer) positions.  If you want more detail, you need hours, minutes and seconds, e.g. represented by a matplotlib timestamp or a float.

Comment: @johanC I see. So it's only updating the y when the hour changes I think is what you're saying. I'll try out using timestamps instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `df['timestamps']` column is full of string timestamps which I had converted to ints representing the number of hours after the first timestamp.
They look like `'2023-01-24 13:26:32'`.

Converting the string timestamps like so fixed the problem:

```
df['timestamps'] = df['timestamps'].apply(;ambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Thanks to JohanC for the comment.